# R - Chi Squared Independence Test - How To?

Tags: r

Using R - to do the Pearsons Chi Squared Independence test - how do I obtain the 'expected' table.

Given:
**OBSERVED**

| airline | late | not_late | total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | 43 | 200 | 243 |
| DEF | 70 | 262 | 332 |
| total | 113 | 462 | 575 |

Desired output:
**EXPECTED**

| airline | late | not_late | total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | 47.75 | 195.25 | 243 |
| DEF | 65.25 | 266.75 | 332 |
| total | 113 | 462 | 575 |

The 'EXPECTED' numbers are calculated as follows....

cell(ABC,late)=(113 x 243)/575 = 47.75

cell(ABC,late)=(113 x 332)/575 = 65.25
etc

Answer (score 0):

Extract the `total` row and column and multiply them with each other using `outer` and divide them by the last value in the dataframe.

```
df[-1] <- outer(df$total, unlist(df[3, -1]))/df[3, 4]
df

#  airline      late not_late total
#1     ABC  47.75478 195.2452   243
#2     DEF  65.24522 266.7548   332
#3   total 113.00000 462.0000   575
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(airline = c("ABC", "DEF", "total"), late = c(43L, 
70L, 113L), not_late = c(200L, 262L, 462L), total = c(243L, 332L, 
575L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```